# How do i install ubuntu from usb from scratch?

Tags: installation

I want to install ubuntu from a usb from startup. without having windows already installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Ubuntu startup disk with `Startup Disk Creator` available by default in Ubuntu.

Go through this [documentation](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [Ubuntu Installation Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) and this [Install Ubuntu 13.04 Guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest) which is well structured and detailed.

Answer (score 0):

> The first thing you should do is head to:
>   Get the latest stable version of Ubuntu from the official website, then use startup disk
>   creator for making the usb bootable( Startup disk creator is available
>   only in Ubuntu or other Linux distributions ) and use Linux live usb
>   creator if you are using windows: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/.

Then proceed with the official documentation: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest